# NVG effect using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an NVG effect using CSS any ideas I don't know where to start and how to add glow and noise effect and all that stuff.

If anyone knows any tips or tried something like that before please guide me thanks <3

Comment: Hi, start by typing `NVG effect using CSS` into google search. You are welcome.

Comment: This codepen might help you : https://codepen.io/vanzo16/pen/oQyPoN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a 'real' infrared feel, you need to *invert* the colors of an image and *desaturate* the result. The inversion will make it feel like objects are glowing. Mix it with a shade of green and you have your NVG.

```css
div {
    background-color: green;
}
img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;

    filter: invert(100%) saturate(0%);

    /* To blend with parent background use: */
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600?random">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to your question you can play with

> background-blend-mode

to achieve different kinds of effects

```css
   div{width: 50vw;
    height: 50vw;
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1671938576119-9e1c53d868dc?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=387&q=80); /*Photo From Unsplash https://unsplash.com/*/
    background-color: green;
    background-blend-mode: overlay;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just that simple:

1. Adding the image to a div
2. Adding a `radial-gradient` with green and black to the div
3. Adding a `mix-blend-mode` with `overlay` to the image itself

**The code:**

```css
div{
    width: 300px; height: 300px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(green, black);
}

img{ mix-blend-mode: overlay; }
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/300x300">
</div>
```